# Laravel sanctum login session timeout in stateful mode

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

Is it possible to log out a user after a certain amount of time in Sanctum stateful mode? 
 For example the user will be logged out after 4 hours or at the end of the day.

I know that you can set the expiration date for API tokens but I want to log out the user after a certain amount of time in stateful mode (session-based auth).

To clarify, ANY user should be logged out after a certain amount of time. Like you see it in bank applications or other websites with greater security.

Comment: So you want to destroy the token after x amount of time user have been logged in ?

Comment: Yes, for example they will be logged out after 4 hours or at the end of the day or whatever.

Comment: Maybe you can build a task scheduler, so, whenever a token is created is deleted after 4 hours lets say

Comment: This may work, but I hoped for a official solution, it is a pretty common thing to let a authentication session expire...

Comment: Can I remind you of every single bank application ever? Or literally any website that needs some kind of greater security.

"You were automaticly singed out. Please log in again." Doesnt that sound familiar to you lol?

Comment: And not "specific" users. Any user should be logged out after say 4 hours.

Comment: In `.env` you have a variable called `SESSION_LIFETIME`. That is stored in minutes. Change it in 240 if you want autologout on 4 hours

Comment: This seems to work, you can answer the question and I'll accept your answer if you'd like.

Comment: done, happy to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .env you have a variable called SESSION_LIFETIME. That is stored in minutes. Change it in 240 if you want autologout on 4 hours