# How to expire a session in Laravel SPA "laravel_session" cookie?"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I currently have a application with Laravel + Sanctum + Vue SPA + Apollo GraphQL.

I'm trying to make a session expire just like in a normal Laravel application but i can't achieve this.

First I make a request to trigger the csrf-cookie of Sanctum on frontend:

```
await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_HTTP}/api/csrf-cookie`, {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

It generates 2 cookies on browser:
`XSRF-COOKIE` and `laravel_session`

On login I use apollo and store the `auth-token` after make a login request:

```
const data = await apolloClient.mutate({
  mutation: Login,
  variables: credentials
})

const token = data.data.login.token

await onLogin(apolloClient, token)


export async function onLogin (apolloClient, token) {
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && token) {
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME, token)
  }
....
```

So i pass the token and cookie to `apolloClient` `link` prop, but i'm not sure if it is needed to pass the XSRF-TOKEN.

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME)

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      'XSRF-TOKEN': Cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN'),
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the problem: The login session never expires, even with the cookie `laravel_session`, i already tried to pass `laravel_session` as a header on my link connection but it doesn't seems to work.

My Laravel `session.php` is set `'expire_on_close' => true` to be sure i can test it i close the browser and re-open, also i'm sure the cookie is set to expire on close because it says on browser cookies info.

Any idea how can i make the laravel session work on a SPA?

Comment: I think your problem related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379196/laravel-sanctum-login-session-timeout-in-stateful-mode) thanx!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cookies to manage the session, your `.env` file should look like this:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

You can also define the session lifetime below

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**Suggestion:** set lifetime to 1 minute, do a login and wait to see if it expires. Let me know!